# How to ignore some calls to the same method with different argument in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, resque

This is my scenario:

After updating an AR object, it fires a bunch of background jobs with Resque. In my specs I’m mocking the call to Resque#enqueue, something in the lines of:

```
it 'should be published' do
  # I need to setup these mocks in many places where I want to mock a specific call to Resque, otherwise it fails
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(NotInterestedJob1, anything)
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(NotInterestedJob2, anything)
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(NotInterestedJob3, anything)

  # I'm only interested in mocking this Resque call.
  Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(PublishJob, anything)
end
```

As you can see, I need to mock all other calls to Resque#enqueue everytime I want to mock a specific call, is there a way to only mock a custom call and ignore the other calls with different arguments?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I think what you've already posted should work - what's the issue?

Comment: Hi Frederick, the issue was that I needed to add all those mocks every where when I wanted to mock a specific Resque call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think that in this case you would need to do what I think of as the method stubbing equivalent of [`as_null_object`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object), but in this case specifically for calls to `Resque.enqueue` that you don't care about:

```
it 'should be published' do
  allow(Resque).to receive(:enqueue) # stub out this message entirely
  expect(Resque).to receive(:enqueue).with(PublishJob, anything)
  call_your_method.that_calls_enqueue
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul, I'm using Rspec 2 so #allow and #receive are not available but I've replaced them with `Resque.stub(:enqueue).and_return(true)` and `Resque.should_receive(:enqueue).with(PublishJob, anything)`